# Why does my test return a nil class error on an attribute it shouldn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I am trying to write a test for my `InvitationsController#Create`.

This is a `POST` http action.

Basically what should happen is, once the `post#create` is first executed, the first thing that needs to do is we need to check to see if a `User` exists in the system for the email passed in via `params[:email]` on the `Post` request.

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how I do this.

I will refactor later, but first I want to get the test functionality working.

This is what I have:

```
describe 'POST #create' do
    context 'when invited user IS an existing user' do
        before :each do
          @users =  [
            attributes_for(:user),
            attributes_for(:user),
            attributes_for(:user)
          ]
        end

       it 'correctly finds User record of invited user' do
          post :create, { email: @users.first[:email] }
          expect(response).to include(@users.first[:email])
        end
    end
end
```

This is the error I get:

```
 1) Users::InvitationsController POST #create when invited user IS an existing user correctly finds User record of invited user
     Failure/Error: post :create, { email: @users.first[:email] }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

 #@myapp/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:22:in 'resource_name'
 # @myapp/gems/devise_invitable-1.3.6/lib/devise_invitable/controllers/helpers.rb:18:in 'authenticate_inviter!'
 # @myapp/gems/devise_invitable-1.3.6/app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb:67:in 'current_inviter'
 # @myapp/gems/devise_invitable-1.3.6/app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb:71:in 'has_invitations_left?'
```

I am using FactoryGirl and it works perfectly, in the sense that it returns valid data for all the data-types. The issue here is how do I get RSpec to actually test for the functionality I need.

**Edit 1**

Added my `:user` factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    association :family_tree
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password "password123"
    password_confirmation "password123"
    bio { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    invitation_relation { Faker::Lorem.word }
    # required if the Devise Confirmable module is used
    confirmed_at Time.now
    gender 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but did you create a Rspec factory called `:user`? You can try without `:each` -> `before do`. The problem comes from your `before`. If `:user` is a `FactoryGirl` model, you should call it like that : `FactoryGirl.create(:user)`.

Comment: Yep, I did create a Factory called `:user`. You can use a few methods as shorthand (e.g. `create, attributes_for, build`, etc.). I tried it with `create` within the `before` block and I am still getting that issue. https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: Can you add you `:user` factory? And around the line 22 of your `devise_controller`? :)

Comment: I added my `:user` factory. I don't have a `devise_controller`. That is the controller within the stock devise gem.

Comment: @bobbystouket - I think this is the line it refers to in the `devise_controller` gem - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.2/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L21-L23

Comment: Ok! Then you need to login before.. It seems that `current_inviter` is `nil`. If course it is because you're not logged in. I'll post a solution in few seconds

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using `Devise` which require you to be logged in before going to the next step. On your error, `Devise` cannot get the same of your `inviter` because he's not logged.

Your test should be like this:

```
describe 'POST #create' do
    context 'when invited user IS an existing user' do
      before :each do
        @users =  [
          attributes_for(:user),
          attributes_for(:user),
          attributes_for(:user)
        ]
        @another_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_for_login)
        sign_in @another_user
      end

      it 'correctly finds User record of invited user' do
        post :create, { email: @users.first[:email] }
        expect(response).to include(@users.first[:email])
      end
   end
end
```

---

Example for `FactoryGirl` model for `Devise`

```
factory :user_for_login, class: User do |u|
  u.email 'admin@myawesomeapp.com'
  u.password 'password'
  u.password_confirmation 'password'
  u.name "MyName"
end
```

Of course, you need to add as much data as your validators want.. Basically for `Devise` you need `email`, `password` and `password_confirmation`. In you case, it seems you also need `name`.

Comment: What should the factory of the `:user_for_login` look like?

Comment: Ok I got the factory working, I just used the regular `:user` factory that exists. But now I am still getting the `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` error.

Comment: Did you log your user?

Comment: I've added an example of factory. Once it's create, you need to use `sign_in @another_user`. Then you can call your `POST` method.

Comment: Ok I just tried that and I get this error now: `Failure/Error: @another_user = create(:user_for_login)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'name=' for #<User:0x007ff4de644080>`. When I get rid of that `u.name` attribute in my FG model, it gives me the same `name nil` error as before.

Comment: Any thoughts on my error above? This solution doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: Your `inviter` should have a name. Is your inviter a `User`? If not, you have to create a factory to create an inviter.